# Solr cloud collections limit

Tags: solrcloud

I have been reading the SolrCloud documentation to understand if there's any limitations around having lots of small collections with all of them syncing across all nodes. Consider something like 100s of collections. Each collection containing around 5- 10k documents at any time.

Most of the documentation talks about few collections with billions of documents. There's not a lot of documentation around handling lot of collections in a single SolrCloud. Does anyone know of any potential issues with such a setup?